# How many bytes will be deallocated with free() after changing the pointer?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, free

I have following piece of code.

```
char* p = malloc(10);
p = p + 1;
free(p);
```

In above code,

1. How does malloc return the memory address when call malloc(10)?
2. How many bytes will be deallocated with *free(p)*?
3. How does *free()* know how many bytes to be deallocated?

Comment: Doing this is undefined behaviour.  You are not allowed to pass a modified pointer to free.  Best you can hope for is a crash.

Comment: you must get an error

Comment: @purec, unfortunately not, it's undefined behaviour

Comment: my compiler gives me error

Comment: *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x086e9009 ***
Aborted

Comment: sorry, not compiler but executable

Comment: Yes, most runtimes would, but don't count on it. Or build with adress sanitizer or run under valgrind.

Comment: That's a "clean" crash, @purec. It's probably what Richard Critten meant as opposed to a silent corruption in memory that causes various issues elsewhere, like shaving your harddrive or formatting your cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the man page for `free` will tell you, any argument except a pointer returned from `malloc` has undefined behaviour:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed

Regarding how `free` knows the size of the block: a typical memory allocator implementation has a header for each block (containing size, freelist pointers, etc.) and `free` knows the size of this header and the offset from the pointer returned by `malloc`.

This also answers your first question: `malloc` allocates such a block and returns a pointer to the start of the actual object.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the explanation.